# Finding a value in an equation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

i`m looking for an easy way to find the value of a variable depending on the result of another one:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = np.arange(0.01, 4.5, 0.0001)
N = (2.63 * 10 ** -16) * ((2.71828 ** (6.93 * T)) - 1) + ((4.05 * 10 ** -6) * T)

plt.plot(N,T)
plt.axis(xmin=-0.001, ymax=5)
plt.show()
```

For example I need the value of T for N= 0,00006762 (Or the closest value). This would be easy if I could solve for T, but I find it easier to create an array of the possible T`s and try the other way.

Comment: Be reminded that if you search for `x` in `y=f(x)`, you are looking to find the *zeros*  or *roots* in `f(x) - y`. Numeric root finding is a complete subject in itself, and there are already many questions and answers on that topic around.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can loop over values of T, calculate N, and compare it with the number you are looking for (0.00006762), and return the closest one you find:

```py
target = 0.00006762
smallest_diff = 1000
best_answer = 'NA'

for T in np.arange(0.01, 4.5, 0.0001):
  N = (2.63 * 10 ** -16) * ((2.71828 ** (6.93 * T)) - 1) + ((4.05 * 10 ** -6) * T)
  if abs(N - target) < smallest_dif:
    smallest_diff = abs(N - target)
    best_answer = T

print(best_answer)
```